# Schedule on website not at the top

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am using wordpress and all in one calendar and I can not seem to get the calendar to be on the top next to the sidebar. Here is the link, http://bikebuckscounty.com/routes/calendar/, greatly appreciate any help. I have tried random css like setting `margin-top` and `padding-top` to `-900px !important;` and nothing has worked. When I use an inspector it seems as if its supposed to start at the top but doesn't. Thanks for all the help.

I got it fixed, not cleanly kinda hacked it. Thanks Guys much appreciate it. Sorry for not putting code up was confused what code.

What I ended up doing was kinda hacking it and putting inline css inside of wordpress page. Sorry for the lack of code was confused.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: What part of the code should I show. Thats why I am having trouble it could be the plugin code, my code, the wp code or the output code?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the following bit of CSS as the image (`<img src="..." id="blueverticallineallotherpages">`) is causing the leftsidecontent div to flow underneath it.

```
.leftsidecontent { position: absolute; }
```

Also, remove the `margin-top: -500px;` from `#ai1ec-container` and the margin-top: -750px;`enter code here` from the unnamed `DIV`

The negative padding on both of these elements is also invalid CSS

**Quick and dirty solution:**

```
#ai1ec-container {
   /* position: absolute; */    //remove or comment this line out
   margin-top: 335px;           //add this line
}
#primarysidebar {
   /* float: right; */    //remove or comment this line out
   margin-left: 592px;    //add this line
   width: 200px;          //existing
   padding-left: 30px;    //existing
   margin-top: 50px;      //existing
}
```

Comment: unforitnaly that worked for the calendar page but it messed up all of the other pages since the footer is now in the middle of the page. Any other suggestions?

Comment: You are more-or-less hacking the positioning of the elements (with gigantic margins)... this will cause many problems as you continue on, especially if you try to make the site behave responsively... I will look into another fix for this and see what I can come up with.

Comment: See the **Quick and Dirty** edits above - check to make sure they dont adversely affect your other pages. If they do, apply the styles to just these containers on that specific page with modified classes [i.e. `.ai1ec-container-calendarMod {...}`] (in addition to the regular ones - but dont forget to change the float to none/clear and the position absolute to relative if you go that route)

Comment: Thanks so much for all of the help, I am almost there, its now fitting although now the comments are overlapped because i made the container absolute. Any suggestions. And yes I know that responsive is going to be a problem, This was the first site I ever made and now in days I use bootstrap and love it. This was originally a static site and it was for free for a charity thats related to my family, thus my first gig. Thanks for everything any suggestions now that its absolute

Comment: I got it fixed, not cleanly kinda hacked it. Thanks Guys much appreciate it. Sorry for not putting code up was confused what code.

Answer (score 0):

I think need to edit ***.ai1ec-dropdown-menu*** in ***ai1ec_render_css***

try

```
  vertical-align:top;
```

Also reset top:100%; in that

Comment: I can't locate ai1ec_render_css where is it? Thanks Aaron

Answer (score 0):

Remove all:

```
margin: -500px
```

Then, you just need to remove clear:both from this class

```
#ai1ec-container {
clear: both;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately that didn't work